# How to retrieve date time from mysql in decending order?

Tags: php, mysql, database, blogs

I have made a simple blog and trying to retrieve the latest post to the top of the blog. the code i have typed already does the ordering for the specific day however when i try to add a another post the next day it goes to the bottom of the page and the ordering of the latest blog works on that specific day.

So what i want is ,my blog to compare all the dates and then post the latest one right at the top..
many thanks

Comment: This isn't a site where we spoon feed everyone, please post what code you have currently and we can work from there.

Comment: No code = No help

Answer (score 1):

You should use order by

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE your_condition ORDER BY your_date_column_name
```

DESC

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Databaseblog ORDER BY date_time(Date) DESC ";     //it doesnt work

Comment: Any otherways ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Databaseblog ORDER BY Date DESC

Comment: This method i have used it before and it only works for that specifc day. Yesterday i have posted some blogs and it got sorted by time from latest post to old.  but today i posted in the same blog and it goes right at the bottom.